# django memcached optimalization

Tags: django, memcached

I am deploying social networking site with django on VPS, my current stack is nginx, postgresql, gunicorn. I am going to add memcached, I will be forced to use {% cache %} tag in my templates or low level api in views though, as each site will be dynamic for authenticated users. I have 1 question regarding {% cache %} tag, lets say i will input a variable within cache tag like so:

```
{% cache 500 x %}
{{ variable }}
{% endcache %}
```

Lets assume that {{ variable }} is in fact very consuming database query written in related view. What would be the best way to prevent database hit from view (lets assume query will be evaluated in view) , should i cache it as well with low level api? If so isnt it a bit redundant as I would cache it in both places? Please give me your thoughs what would be the most convenient method. Btw, I know that this example is trivial, if I only wanted to cache variable I could do this in view, but I will surely need to use cache tag to cache some loops, multiple html lines generated by python etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the usage of authentication in your site doesn't involve the usage of low level cache in both sides views and templates, note for instance you can do something like `{% cache 500 user %}` and that will save different chunk of code of each user of your site.

Answering your second question: in general, you can prevent database hits just caching into the templates. Evaluate the query there instead of doing into the view, and make a dynamic clean up of the keys when the content changes instead of using fixed expiration times, that way let you get better performance result. Also, take in mind `cache` tag saves just chunk of HTML code.